# Displaying weekday on Active Admin column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

How it's possible to display the weekday next to a date ?

```
column :start_date    #displaying for example 29 Jan. 2016
```

How to echo it as Friday, 29 Jan. 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) method.

```
column "Start Date:" do |post|
  post.start_date.strftime("%A, %d %b. %Y")
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You saved my day !

Comment: I'm very sorry for my late response. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @AlexPogo You still there ? then ping me please.